# MySQL: как объединить значения из разных столбцов в одном?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица в которой значения разбросаны по двум столбцам. Если в одном столбце нет значения, то оно обязательно есть во втором. Например столбец `region_name` соответствует столбцу `region_name1`, `status` - `status`:

```
+------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+---------+
| id   | region_name   |  status       | region_name1       | status1 |
+------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+---------+
|    1 | Хакасия       | Респ          | NULL               | NULL    |
|    2 | Хакасия       | Респ          | NULL               | NULL    |
|    3 | NULL          | NULL          | Оренбургская       | обл     |
|    4 | NULL          | NULL          | Краснодарский      | край    |
|    5 | Башкортостан  | Респ          | NULL               | NULL    |
|    6 | NULL          | NULL          | Татарстан          | Респ    |
|    7 | Адыгея        | Респ          | NULL               | NULL    |
|    8 | NULL          | NULL          | Татарстан          | Респ    |
|    9 | Ростовская    | обл           | NULL               | NULL    |
|   10 | Тыва          | Респ          | NULL               | NULL    |
|   11 | NULL          | NULL          | Ростовская         | обл     |
|   12 | NULL          | NULL          | Северная Осетия    | Респ    |
|   13 | Свердловская  | обл           | NULL               | NULL    |
+------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+---------+
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как через SELECT объединить данные из двух столбцов в одном? Возможно, это можно сделать с условием: 'Если в одном столбце значение равно NULL, то это значение равно значению из второго столбца'?

Чтобы итогом выборки SELECT стала таблица:

```
+------+------------------------------------------+---------------+
| id   | region_name                              | region_status |
+------+------------------------------------------+---------------+
|    1 | Хакасия                                  | Респ          |
|    2 | Хакасия                                  | Респ          |
|    3 | Оренбургская                             | обл           |
|    4 | Краснодарский                            | край          |
|    5 | Башкортостан                             | Респ          | 
|    6 | Татарстан                                | Респ          |
|    7 | Адыгея                                   | Респ          |
|    8 | Татарстан                                | Респ          |
|    9 | Ростовская                               | обл           |
|   10 | Тыва                                     | Респ          |
|   11 | Ростовская                               | обл           |
|   12 | Северная Осетия                          | Респ          |
|   13 | Свердловская                             | обл           | 
+------+------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Как гарантируется, что если region_nameX - not null, то и statusX тоже not null (и в обратном порядке)? Как гарантируется, что если в одной паре полей (region_nameX, statusX) не-null значения, то в другой null? Причём гарантируется - не алгоритмами клиентской части, а именно подсистемой целостности MySQL-сервера? Если никак - что делать с записью, если для неё наблюдаются описанные выше "ненормальности"?

Comment: @Akina,  Представленная мной таблица со значениями  region_nameX  и statusX  это результат запроса с LEFT JOIN из разных таблиц. Соответственно region_name и status - это одна таблица, где у городов  parent_id является регион; А region_name1 и status1 это таблица где у районов parent_id регион. Соответственно не могут быть пересечения о которых вы упомянули. Это база  ФИАС. Выделил в отдельные таблицы области, районы и города. Вот и играюсь с ними.

Comment: *Представленная мной таблица со значениями region_nameX и statusX это результат запроса с LEFT JOIN из разных таблиц.* Тогда почему эти данные не собираются сразу в этом запросе в одно поле? `SELECT ... , COALESCE(t1.field, t2.field) AS field ... FROM main LEFT JOIN slave AS t1 ... LEFT JOIN slave AS t2 ...`

Comment: @Akina, Вы правы, можно было сделать так! Но я из-за того, что недостаточно владею SQL - просто не сообразил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [ifnull()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
select
  id,
  ifnull(region_name, region_name1) as region_name,
  ifnull(status, status1) as region_status
from table_name
where ...
```